# How to get the string in a td when clicking inside a td which comes later than the first td but in the same tr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>Position1</td>
        <td>Operation1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name2</td>
        <td>Position2</td>
        <td>Operation2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to get the string in the first `<td>` when I click the last `<td>` inside the same `<tr>`,
for example, if I click in the `<td>` contains "Operation1", I could get a string with the value "Name1".
How to do  this? (In reality, the strings among different `<td>`s have not any relationship, like the same postfix here)
Oh, BTW, this table is created by using jQuery Datatables plug-in.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it, such as:

```
$('td').parent().children().filter('td:first');
$('td').parent('tr').find('td:first');
$('td').siblings('td:first');
```

[**Here's a jsFiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mJDZ/2/)

Comment: How about: `$(this).parents('tr').find('td:first')`

Comment: @elclanrs Yes, that is a better way :p

Comment: or `$(this).siblings('td:first')`

Comment: I think you rather use `.parent()` instead of `.parents()` because `.parents()` will grab all ancestors..

Comment: Updated guys, sorry for my rubbish selector :( I haven't slept in a long, long time

Comment: :) np..  I'm feeling like that too now

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$(document).on('click', 'td:last', function(){
    $(this).siblings(':first')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Javascript only solution for a static page, this attaches an event listener to the `tr` and intercepts the click events of its children. the contents of the `tr` can be dynamic.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("table"), function (table) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(table.getElementsByTagName("tr"), function (tr) {
        tr.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
            var children = this.children,
                length = children.length;

            if (length && children[length - 1] === evt.target) {
                alert(children[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
            }
        }, false);
    });
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Ym9TH/)

Which in jquery terms would be

```
$("table tr").on("click", function (evt) {
    var target = $(evt.target);

    if (target.parent().children().last().get(0) === evt.target) {
        alert(target.parent().children().first().text());
    }
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/2AN59/)

Or rather than set an event listener per `tr` element ("bubbling"), you could also use event "bubbling" and move it all the way out to `document` (what those at jquery call Event Delegation, [jquery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)), this will allow for quite a dynamic system if you add and remove rows from your table, or even whole tables.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target;

    if (target.nodeName === "TD" && target.parentNode.children[target.parentNode.children.length - 1] === target) {
        alert(target.parentNode.children[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
    }
}, false);
```

On jsfid[d](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/2BS66/)le

Or using jquery delegation

```
$(document).on("click", "td", function (evt) {
    var target = $(evt.target);

    if (target.parent().children().last().get(0) === evt.target) {
        alert(target.siblings().first().text());
    }
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/2AN59/)